# Decode into struct when passed as interface{} returns map

Tags: go

When using mongo-driver, I have this struct which I pass to the get function as interface{}. The problem is when I use the Decode method, it returns a map while I was expecting a struct of the proper type. I found a similar question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058902/json-decode-into-struct-as-interface-yields-mapstringinterface-not-struct) but the solution didnt work for me, the program crashes.

```
type Item struct {
 //whatever
}

type mymodel struct {
    I            interface{} 
    F            interface{}
    DatabaseName string
    Collection   string
}

func Do(){
    var item Item
    var filter Item

    m:= mymodel{I: item, F: filter}
    res,_ := get(m)
}

func get(m mymodel) (*interface{}, error) {

    c := database.DBCon.Database("whatever").Collection("whatever")

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    err := c.FindOne(ctx, m.F).Decode(&m.I)
    if err != nil {
        log.Log.Info(err)
        return nil, err
    }


    return &m.I, nil

}
```

Comment: You need to make the interface fields `I` and `F` store a pointer (maybe not `F` since you're not decoding anything into that), and then pass them directly to `Decode`, without anymore `&`. That is `m:= mymodel{I: &item, F: &filter}`, and then `.Decode(m.I)`.

Comment: that worked perfectly! many thanks. If you post it as an answer ill mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the interface fields `I` and `F` store a pointer to the instance into which you want to decode the data (maybe not `F` since you're not decoding anything into that), and then pass them directly to `Decode`, without any more address operations (`&x`).

For example:

```
func Do(){
    var item Item
    var filter Item

    m:= mymodel{I: &item, F: filter}
    res,_ := get(m)
}

func get(m mymodel) (*interface{}, error) {
    c := database.DBCon.Database("whatever").Collection("whatever")

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    err := c.FindOne(ctx, m.F).Decode(m.I)
    if err != nil {
        log.Log.Info(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return &m.I, nil
}
```